# Dealing with a 3rd party library who's function call causes heap corruptions when P/Invoking

Tags: c#, .net, c, exception, pinvoke

I have created a library wrapper which invokes FlexNet Publisher. It is written in C. I am trying to P/Invoke it:

```
[DllImport("lmgr11.dll")]
public static extern void free_job();
```

Its implementation is fairly simple:

```
void WINAPI free_job()
{
    if (jobPtr != NULL)
        lc_free_job(jobPtr);
    jobPtr = NULL;
}
```

The documentation says that `lc_free_job` should free a job as well as all resources. Calling `lc_free_job` works just fine from native code (I made an ATL object expose a wrapper to it through a COM object and I can consume this method all day long from a Visual C++ console application, so I know it must work).

However, from C#, when I try to P/Invoke this method, I get the following error which crashes my application:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFA39358283 (ntdll.dll) in
>   CerberusTestHarness.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted
>   (parameters: 0x00007FFA393AF6B0).

Why is this? Can I catch it or circumvent it in any way? I can't seem to catch the exception if I wrap the call in a try-catch because its not throwing a .NET exception. Note that I don't have the source code for `lc_free_job` so I can't inspect it or view its source code, unfortunately. Its written in C.

Comment: The defect is surely in your code. You should find it and fix it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't think it is, I would have caught it by now. The code is calling the same methods and follows the same logic from either my unmanaged test harness or my managed test harness.

Comment: You think that is the case, but the evidence would appear to suggest otherwise.

Comment: Did you try to play with different options provided by `DllImport`, such as `CallingConvention` for example?

Comment: @Evk Please don't suggest the application of trial and error. Does that ever work for you? The calling convention is clearly correct in the code as presented.

Comment: @Evk Yes, I did try a variety of calling conventions.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan There are 3 simple API calls, and I have checked them yet again, following your brilliant suggestion. Both managed and unmanaged implementations use the exact same method calls to this library and the same parameters passed to it. I really don't understand why its not working for me.

Comment: @Ðаn I can verify that `lc_free_job` is the problem here, which implies that `jobPtr` has been set up correctly at this point in the application and is not null, so whatever this function is doing in C from the 3rd party library, its generating a heap corruption only when its P/Invoked. This is as MVE as it gets. Welcome to the world of 3rd party libraries without source code available, mate.

Comment: Well, call me a sceptic, but I don't believe that the defect isn't in your code.

Comment: Don't take my word on it, but as I remember heap corruption can happen in another part of your code, but is revealed when you call `free_job` because it attempts to free memory. So still maybe problem is not in `lc_free_job` by itself.

Comment: @Ðаn I've been debating doing that as a last resort.

Comment: "Calling lc_free_job works just fine" Seeming to work fine is one typical form of undefined behavior, a latent bug which doesn't reveal itself until you port the program to some other platform. It is a well-known phenomenon that a crash on the `free()` line only means that somewhere in the program there's a bug destroying the heap. It is not necessarily related to the particular variable you are trying to free.

Comment: What you have now is some 3-4 very experienced devs telling you with their gut instinct ("gut debugging") that the bug is most likely inside your own code. The sensible thing to do then, is to remain very humble and go through all the code that you thought was fine. Look for array and pointer-related bugs, uninitialized variables, the usual classic bugs.

Comment: @Lundin 4-5 now ;)

Comment: Alright, you meanies were right. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was due to my C# P/Invoke code from a previous invocation. Hopefully this helps anyone else who comes across the same issue.

I had defined this P/Invoke to get an error string back from a function which returns `char *`:

```
[DllImport("lmgr11.dll")]
public static extern string errstring();
```

I was calling it every time something failed in my 3rd party library as above. This is not the correct way to P/Invoke a method which returns `char *`. Otherwise, when freeing the error from the native side, it will cause a heap corruption due to the way this string was marshaled.

It needed to be defined like this:

```
[DllImport("lmgr11.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr errstring();
```

And called as follows:

```
var errorMessage = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(errstring());
```

Comment: how did you compile lmgr11.dll or obtain it?